# Show which tokens were not found in an Elasticsearch 8 full-text search

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there a way to determine which words (tokens) in a phrase was or wasn't found during full text search. I need it to do something like Google does:

[image]

Under each query result it shows which part of phrase is missing, like: Missing: <s>dragons</s>. I didn't find anything helpful in the documentation, so any suggestions are welcome.

**ES version: 8.7**